# Find rank $AB=I_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{m,n} (\mathbb R)$, $B \in M\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb R)$ and $AB=I_m$. If $rankA=r$ then:

$i)r>m$

$ii)r<m$

$iii)r=m$

$iv)r>n$

Choose a right answer and explain. After that say is $m\le n$ or $n\le m$ and explain.

since $I_m=AB$ that mean that every column of matrix $I_m$ is linear combination of column matrix $A$, since $I_m$ have m linear independent column and every column is represent as linear combination of column matrix A then $rankA=m$. For second part since dimension of column is equal the dimension of row that mean that $n=m$ or $n>m$ so $m\le n$ is this ok?

Comment: You are right, but to conclude $rank(A)=m$ in 4th line you have to use these facts - $dim(column\ space\ of\  A) ≥ m $ since column space of A contains columns of $I_m$, $dim(row\ space\ of\ A)=dim(column\ space\ of\  A)$ since $ row\ rank = column\ rank$ , $dim(row\ space\ of\  A)≤m$ since A has exactly m-rows.

Comment: I think it is ok. Just a little remark: If you read this in terms of the associated linear mappings, say $\alpha$ to $A$ and $\beta$ to $B$, then $AB=I_m$ says that $\alpha\circ\beta=\operatorname{id}$. Thus $\alpha is surjectivee and $\beta$ is injective which gives you another possibility of explaining.